# jQuery .focus() not working with a dynamically generated list item using ng-repeat (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am making a website accessible by keyboard and I am trying to make a dropdown menu keyboard accessible. The element with the id= list-0 is what I am trying to get focus to.

The HTML is:

```
<dl class="office-type-dropdown"> 
                        <dt tabindex=0 href="#" id='emerald-button' role="button" aria-haspopup="true" ng-keydown="b_onKeyDown($event)">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);">    
                                <p class="multiSel">
                                    <span ng-repeat="obj in selectedItems">{{obj}}</span>
                                </p>  
                            </a>
                        </dt>

                        <dd>
                            <div class="mutliSelect">
                                <ul role="menu" id="office-select-menu">
                                    <li ng-repeat="obj in officeTypes" id="list-{{$index}}" aria-posinset="{{$index+1}}" ng-keydown="m_onKeyDown($event)">
                                        <label for="checkbox-{{index}}">
                                            <input tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" id="checkbox-{{$index}}" type="checkbox"  class="{{obj.class}}" ng-change='onCompleteFilter(obj)' ng-model="obj.checked">
                                            {{obj.text}}
                                        </label>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
```

THE jQuery that I am trying to make the list item focus is:

```
$scope.b_onKeyDown = function ($event) {
    var key = event.which;
    if(key == 13){
        $('#office-select-menu').toggle();
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#emerald-button').blur();
                $('#list-0').attr("autofocus","autofocus");
                $('#list-0').focus();
            }, 100);
    }
}
```

After searching other questions I have added SetTimeOut and autofocus but they don't work either. The focus however is going to the html tag instead, when I do document.activeElement.innerHTML it spits out the entire HTML.

Any advice would be great. Thank You

Comment: Why are you trying to mix jquery with angularjs. You can use angular directives to achieve this type of functionality.

Comment: Please advise on how to or refer me to an example online. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

A jquery ID cannot have a '-' in it unless you escape it.

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ I think '-' is not included in this list. Also I have '-' working all throughout my website. Thanks for the help though!